# error: <anonymous m$1> is not abstract and does not override abstrac method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java

I have this Code of an Action Listener:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class m extends Applet
{
    Button b1=new Button("click here");

    public void init()
    {
       b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
            public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                  System.out.println("Button was clicked ");
            }
       });
       add(b1);
    }
}
```

which produces this Error:

```
error: <anonymous m$1> is not abstract and does not override abstrac method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
```

Does anybody know what the reason for this error is?

Comment: the overriden method of the `ActionListener` should be called `actionPerformed` and not `ActionPerformed`

Comment: can any1 please suggest me to overcome that problem thanks in advance

Comment: @KevinEsche Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `ActionPerformed` should be named `actionPerformed`. Java method names are case sensitive.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
              System.out.println("Button was clicked ");
        }
   });
```